# How to prevent Object property bound to text box from changing CollectionViewSource of a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have EraNumber property of MachineViewModel that is bound to a text box text property,and CollectionViewSource of MachineViewModel that is bound to a datagrid.
Whenever I change the value of the text box ,every Item of the collection view source that is bound to the datagrid changes to the value of the text box.

```
         >
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Vm:MachineViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="vehiclesGrid" Width="390" ShowGridLines="false"  >
   
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
       
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="lblVehicleEra" Content="Era Number"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtVehicleEra" Grid.Column="2"   PreviewTextInput="numbersOnly" Text="{Binding Era, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource TextError}" messenger:CommandBehavior.RoutedEventName="LostFocus" messenger:CommandBehavior.TheCommandToRun="{Binding EraNumberChangedCommand}" />
```

```
  <DataGrid  x:Name="dataDisplayReport"  
                           EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
                           EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="Auto" 
                           AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsMachines}}"
                        CanUserAddRows="False"  
                           >
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateMachine}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                   
            
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `BindingMode` to `OneWay` should do it.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Era, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Here's [more info about binding modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#fields).

Comment: I tried that one.when I change the Mode to OneWay, something else fails.